# Is there a way to get all activity since Rarible's launch using their api?

Tags: api, web-scraping, data-mining, cryptocurrency, nft

I've tried using the continuation token, but it stops about 10 days back. The size is limited to 1000 per page. Since I couldn't get all activities, I was going to get all collections, and try to get all activities of each collection. When I tried to get all collections, the continuation token only allowed me to get back 2 pages of 1000, so only returned 2000 collections. Could the api not be functioning correctly right now? I've never scraped data like this, but have tried many configurations of the url. I've tried asking in the Rarible protocol discord, but no one would respond. I also tried Reddit, and the same happened. Maybe I'm doing something foolish? If someone could just help point me in the right direction, I'm at my wits end. Thanks.

here's a link to the api: https://api.rarible.org/v0.1/doc#operation/getAllCollections

Edit: maybe someone could try something similar, just as a sanity check or something, I don't know

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I wrote some code to reproduce this bug https://gist.github.com/kylemcdonald/d0e5fa604b89cc4c7757b70a8396c1cd

Comment: @KyleMcDonald Sorry it took so long to respond, I really need to decrease the number of accounts I have across the internet so I'm not so flaky. But sadly, no I never solved it. I just settled for what I could get. Hopefully you were able to achieve what you needed.